# Using awk and if statement

Tags: awk

I need to use an AWK command to do a compare against 2 numbers. if 1 number is higher the the other then Fire a Command. The unix shell is very stripped down but does support awk. I am new to this and need a little help.

I have tried a bunch of diffrent ways. I dont know what I am missing.

```
if (awk '{$1 > 80}' $OUTPUT3) echo 'FireActions' else fi
```

So if the number in the variable $OUTPUT3 is higher then 80, fire actions. Otherwise ignore.

Currently no actions fire.

Comment: Which shell is it? And what's exactly in `$OUTPUT3`, is it an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` is a little awkward for this particular case.  You need to return 0 to indicate success, and non-zero to indicate failure, which inverts the boolean 0 == false and 1 == true.  But it's not too bad:

```
if awk 'END{ exit !($1 > 80)}' $OUTPUT3; then echo 'FireActions'; else ...; fi
```

The above assume $OUTPUT3 contains the name of an input file, which does not appear to be what you want.  If you just want to know if $OUTPUT3 is greater than 80, awk is the wrong tool.  You want

```
if test "$OUTPUT3" -gt 80; then ...; fi
```

If for some reason you really want to use awk, you could do:

```
if echo $OUTPUT3 | awk 'END{ exit !($1 > 80)}'; then echo 'FireActions'; fi
```

or

```
if awk 'END{ exit !(c > 80)}' c="$OUTPUT3" < /dev/null ; then echo 'FireActions'; fi
```

Comment: Ah ! Thank you very much. I didnt realize that awk relied on the input being a file. I thought I could use any variable. Unfortunaly I have to use awk.

This is not supported: if test "$OUTPUT3" -gt 80; then ...; fi Thats what I tried originally.

This worked perfect: if echo $OUTPUT3 | awk 'END{ exit !($1 > 80)}'; then echo 'FireActions'; fi 

I dont understand this part; END{ exit !
Can you Explain it?

Comment: The `END` pattern tells awk to execute the given action, which is to exit.  The comparison `$1 > 80` evaluates to true (non-zero) or false(zero), and we add the `!` to invert those values, since the shell's `if` will take zero as success, and non-zero as failure.

Comment: Referencing the value of $1 in the END section is undefined behavior per POSIX so in some awks it'll be the value of $1 from the last record read but in others it'll be null and it could be anything else too and still be POSIX compliant. For a portable solution instead of `awk 'END{ exit !($1 > 80)}'` you'd need `awk '{p=$1} END{ exit !(p > 80)}'` or similar.

Comment: @Ed Morton Thanks for that.  Maybe it's time to (once again) dump `awk` for `perl`.  I feel like I do that every few years...  We need another standard!  I wonder if our grandchildren will still be dealing with these issues :)

Comment: I think for this particular case, it's probably better to just exit on the first line of input rather than in an END block.

Comment: Thank you all for the explanations. Very Helpful !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ OUTPUT3=80
$ awk -v val="$OUTPUT3" 'BEGIN{if (val>80) print "FireActions"}'
$ OUTPUT3=81
$ awk -v val="$OUTPUT3" 'BEGIN{if (val>80) print "FireActions"}'
FireActions
```

To run a command like "FireActions":

```
awk -v val="$OUTPUT3" 'BEGIN{if (val>80) system("FireActions")}'
```